# Python splitting group of lines in text file in separate files based on pattern

Tags: python

I have text file structured as following:

`{0: (566, 906), 1: (434, 750), 2: (1021, 649), 3: (857, 567), 4: (761, 654), 5: (929, 534), 6: (1418, 465), 7: (1345, 985), 8: (753,    465), 9: (134, 522), 10: (614, 473), 11: (1868, 591), 12: (881, 473),    13: (1112, 434), 14: (688, 451), 15: (843, 423)} {0: (563, 920), 1:    (429, 755), 2: (1023, 652), 3: (859, 569), 4: (761, 659), 5: (931,    536), 6: (1410, 465), 7: (1363, 988), 8: (753, 466), 9: (134, 522),    10: (613, 475), 11: (1858, 584), 12: (881, 474), 13: (1109, 434), 14:    (688, 452), 16: (1702, 617), 17: (945, 463), 18: (820, 400)} {0:    (558, 934), 1: (424, 763), 2: (1025, 653), 3: (861, 572), 4: (762,    663), 5: (931, 537), 6: (1404, 463), 7: (1379, 993), 8: (753, 466),    9: (134, 522), 10: (613, 476), 11: (1849, 578), 12: (881, 475), 13:    (1101, 431), 14: (688, 453), 17: (947, 464), 19: (1677, 610)}`

Every number before `:` represents an object number and numbers between braces represent `x,y` coordinates the whole line between `{}`    represents all objects "vehicles" in the video frame.

Can I group all objects "vehicles" and their numbers for every frame in separate files using python?

The output should be something like this:

#### `file1.text`

object number 0 and it's coordinates in all frames

```
0: (566, 906) 0: (563, 920) 0: (558, 934)
```

#### file2.text

object number 1 and it's coordinates in all frames

```
1:    (434, 750) 1: (429, 755) 1: (424, 763)
```

and so on for all objects in    all data frame

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a question. In particular, it is important to have a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or in your case what you have tried that isn’t working the way you need.

Comment: Of course you can.  It's just rearranging data.  Your text file can be read as a series of JSON strings.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.  Straightforward; just read the data into a list of dictionaries, then reformat it into a dictionary of lists.

```
import ast
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data = [ast.literal_eval(ln) for ln in open('x.json')]
print(data)

result = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    for k,v in row.items():
        result[k].append(v)
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{0: (566, 906), 1: (434, 750), 2: (1021, 649), 3: (857, 567), 4: (761, 654), 5: (929, 534), 6: (1418, 465), 7: (1345, 985), 8: (753, 465), 9: (134, 522), 10: (614, 473), 11: (1868, 591), 12: (881, 473), 13: (1112, 434), 14: (688, 451), 15: (843, 423)}, {0: (563, 920), 1: (429, 755), 2: (1023, 652), 3: (859, 569), 4: (761, 659), 5: (931, 536), 6: (1410, 465), 7: (1363, 988), 8: (753, 466), 9: (134, 522), 10: (613, 475), 11: (1858, 584), 12: (881, 474), 13: (1109, 434), 14: (688, 452), 16: (1702, 617), 17: (945, 463), 18: (820, 400)}, {0: (558, 934), 1: (424, 763), 2: (1025, 653), 3: (861, 572), 4: (762, 663), 5: (931, 537), 6: (1404, 463), 7: (1379, 993), 8: (753, 466), 9: (134, 522), 10: (613, 476), 11: (1849, 578), 12: (881, 475), 13: (1101, 431), 14: (688, 453), 17: (947, 464), 19: (1677, 610)}]
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {0: [(566, 906), (563, 920), (558, 934)],
             1: [(434, 750), (429, 755), (424, 763)],
             2: [(1021, 649), (1023, 652), (1025, 653)],
             3: [(857, 567), (859, 569), (861, 572)],
             4: [(761, 654), (761, 659), (762, 663)],
             5: [(929, 534), (931, 536), (931, 537)],
             6: [(1418, 465), (1410, 465), (1404, 463)],
             7: [(1345, 985), (1363, 988), (1379, 993)],
             8: [(753, 465), (753, 466), (753, 466)],
             9: [(134, 522), (134, 522), (134, 522)],
             10: [(614, 473), (613, 475), (613, 476)],
             11: [(1868, 591), (1858, 584), (1849, 578)],
             12: [(881, 473), (881, 474), (881, 475)],
             13: [(1112, 434), (1109, 434), (1101, 431)],
             14: [(688, 451), (688, 452), (688, 453)],
             15: [(843, 423)],
             16: [(1702, 617)],
             17: [(945, 463), (947, 464)],
             18: [(820, 400)],
             19: [(1677, 610)]})
```

Comment: this solution helped me a lot but how can i print each value in separate text file
like this 1: [(434, 750), (429, 755), (424, 763)] in separate file and so on .

Comment: Come on, that's a trivial change to this code.  You can write that yourself.  It's a simple `for` loop.